# dotnet publish failing using .NET Core 1.1 and new VS 2017 project format

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

We've recently migrated to Visual Studio 2017 Update 2. We have a .NET Core 1.1 app which targets .NET Framework 4.6.1 only, and has project references to .NET Framework class libraries in the same solution. We are using the 1.0.4 SDK version of dotnet.

One of the project references contains T4 templates which are configured to run on build. This requires importing `Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets` and related assemblies, so that the T4 templates can be transformed by MSBuild. These assemblies in turn require .NET Framework 4.6 assemblies (System, System.Data, System.Xml, etc).

Visual Studio 2017 has no problems building the code, however when we try to use `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish` in our TeamCity builds, the command fails with the following output:

`c:\xxx\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(340,5): error MSB4018: The "TransformTemplates" task failed unexpectedly.
c:\xxx\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(340,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
c:\xxx\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets(340,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

Based on the research I've done so far, the .NET Framework references required to run the T4 transformation task are not being loaded by the dotnet CLI, but they are by Visual Studio, due to entirely separate MSBuild toolchains.

Is there any way to make `dotnet publish` work in the same manner as Visual Studio? This issue has completely broken our CI / CD trains.

**NOTE:** I tried including .NET Standard as a target framework to see if that might work, but we use several packages that are not compatible so that isn't an option (Entity Framework 6.1, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dotnet` based commands run on a .NET Core build of MSBuild so it is unable to load full framework assemblies. If there are no .NET Core or .NET Standard versions of these assemblies, loading them during builds of the .NET Core version of MSBuild is impossible at the moment (this may become possible with the move to .NET Core 2.0).

In order to get CI/CD working, you need to use the VS version of MSBuild. `dotnet publish` only forwards to msbuild so you can get the same behaviour passing parameters to msbuild. For example:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

becomes

```
msbuild /m /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release
```